# Turning list of pairs into list of pairs of pairs that share last item with first or vice versa

Tags: python, tuples

I have a list of tuples like `li = [('aa', 'bb'), ('bb','cc'), ('dd', 'ee')]`. From `li` I want to produce a list of pairs of tuples where the first element of one tuple in `li` is equal to the second element in another element of `li`. In the example here, the output list would be a list including a single pair of tuples:

```
[(('aa', 'bb'), ('bb', 'cc'))]
```

This is easy enough for short `li` lists. I have done it for example by something like

```
joints = []
for pair in itertools.permutations(li, r=2):
    if pair[0][1] == pair[1][0]:
        joints += ((pair[0][0], pair[0][1]), (pair[1][0], pair[1][1]))
```

However, with long lists `li` the total number of all length-2 permutations quickly explodes and becomes unmanageable.

I think there must be a more feasible way to do this, perhaps using  matrix multiplication or hash tables. What's a reasonable way to do this for longer (e.g. 5000+-length) lists?

Comment: "topological sort"

Comment: what about duplicate cases, and tuples can be match in two case?

Comment: @Kasramvd There are no duplicates in `li`, but each element can match with many other elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary, in order to collect the expected pairs. And as a more pythonic approach you can use `defaultdict()` and `deque` function from `collections` module, in order to preserve the relevant pairs for each pair in a `deque`:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict, deque
>>> d = defaultdict(deque)

>>> for i, j in li:
...     for k, t in li:
...        if (i, j) != (k, t) and (i == t or j == k):
...             d[(i, j)].append((k, t))
... 
>>> 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'collections.deque'>,
            {('dd', 'ee'): deque([('ee', 'mm')]),
             ('rr', 'cc'): deque([('cc', 'tt')]),
             ('cc', 'tt'): deque([('bb', 'cc'), ('rr', 'cc')]),
             ('aa', 'bb'): deque([('bb', 'cc')]),
             ('ee', 'mm'): deque([('dd', 'ee')]),
             ('bb', 'cc'): deque([('aa', 'bb'), ('cc', 'tt')])})
```

And for creating the desire list of tuples you can use a list comprehension, by iterating over the dictionary items:

```
>>> [[(k, v) for v in values] for k, values in d.items()]
[[(('dd', 'ee'), ('ee', 'mm'))], [(('rr', 'cc'), ('cc', 'tt'))], [(('cc', 'tt'), ('bb', 'cc')), (('cc', 'tt'), ('rr', 'cc'))], [(('aa', 'bb'), ('bb', 'cc'))], [(('ee', 'mm'), ('dd', 'ee'))], [(('bb', 'cc'), ('aa', 'bb')), (('bb', 'cc'), ('cc', 'tt'))]]
```

Note that you could simply use `list` as your `defaultdict`'s function if you don't want to do any extra operation on result, but if you want to do more operations on result like popping, appending at both sides, rotating, etc. the `deque` is a good choice since provide you with constant order for most of that operations.

More concise way by `itertools.permutations`:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for i, j permutations(li, 2):
...        if (i == t or j == k):
...             d[(i, j)].append((k, t))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very nice. If I understand what you're saying, I think the condition I want is is actually `j == k` not `(i == t or j == k)`. I intend for order to be significant: From `[('a,'b'), ('b','c')]` I would want to produce `(('a', 'b'), ('b','c'))` but not `(('b', 'c'), ('a', 'b'))`.

Comment: @Hatshepsut Your question was vague, feel free to change it based on your need ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Maintain two sets - elements at first indices and elements at second indices. From the original list, only append those tuples where at least one of the elements is in both the sets.

```
li = [('aa', 'bb'), ('bb','cc'), ('dd', 'ee')]

first_pos = {x for x, y in li}
second_pos = {y for x, y in li}

arr = [(x, y) for x, y in li if (x in first_pos and x in second_pos) or (y in
    first_pos and y in second_pos)]

print(arr)
```

Output -

```
[('aa', 'bb'), ('bb', 'cc')]
```